# Collapse text by group and convert to list

Tags: r, dplyr

I normally like to work with tidy data, but I am using a package that requires me to transform the data into a list of a specific form. The data I have is the following

```
  quantity itemnumber     id
     <int> <chr>       <int>
1        1 u           99732
2        2 a          100229
3        1 c          100229
4        1 x          100229
5        1 s          100229
6        5 r           99732
7        1 e           99732
8        1 i          100229
9        3 y           99732
```

I need to make it so `str(mydata)` looks like the following:

```
List of 2
 $ id 99732    : chr [1:10] "u" "r" "r" "r" "r" "r" "e" "y" "y" "y"
 $ id 100229    : chr [1:6] "a" "a" "c" "x" "s" "i"
```

My current solution is

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(itemnumber=paste(itemnumber,collapse=''))
```

but this does not get me all of the way there. I still have a data frame and the replications of the `itemnumbers` were not accounted for.

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: for an old fashioned way, `with(dat, split(rep(itemnumber, quantity), rep(id, quantity)))`

Comment: @user20650 That did it. Submit as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` using `id` as the group, and `rep`eat each term by the `quantity` required.

```
with(dat, split(rep(itemnumber, quantity), rep(id, quantity)))
```

---

```
dat = read.table(header=TRUE, text="  quantity itemnumber     id
1        1 u           99732
2        2 a          100229
3        1 c          100229
4        1 x          100229
5        1 s          100229
6        5 r           99732
7        1 e           99732
8        1 i          100229
9        3 y           99732", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: I got my hands on a much larger data set. Would you know of a way to do the same thing as above, but a lot faster?

Comment: not really. Is that your final outcome, or are you then applying a function or combining them. If so, then there may be faster ways for the full process.